# How to fix Latex Rendering issue in Jupyterlab?

Tags: latex, jupyter-lab

How do I fix this so that it renders?

Windows 11, Jupyter lab.

[image]

Comment: Usually you just need $,  or double dollar signs for a block, at the start and end of Latex/MathJax or simpler MAthJAx style for a fraction in Jupyter, see [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/how-to-display-a-fraction-in-a-markdown-cell/20657?u=fomightez). Please include code as text in your post for easier troubleshooting for those trying to help you.